# How to change html content using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to change html content using JavaScript or JQuery?

[image]

I want to change contents from 1 to 5 sequentially according to the time as stated in the picture. What should I do using JavaScript or JQuery?
Please let me know if you have any search keywords or links to related documents.

Comment: Using cookies you could store when the user last visited the page and what state they were on when they did visit. Then you're script would create the boxes dynamically based on that informaiton

Comment: @Kinglish Is there any other way besides cookies?

Comment: You can use localstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the picture, I assume that you want to randomly shuffle the contents each day.
you can do this by using an array of contents and on each day randomly select an element from the array and set it as the content of div using DOM manipulation.